# Material UI: Grid does not put select in row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new in full stack developing and I'm trying to code something to understand better frontend with React JS and Material UI. I've write a page that shows posts in backend but I want to Select Items all in a row, on Material UI website I've read that I've to write like this in order to show elements in a row:

Marketplace.js

```
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import regioni from '../utils/where'

import Adv from '../components/marketplace/Adv';
import NewAdv from '../components/marketplace/NewAdv';
import Profile from '../components/profile/Profile';
import PostSkeleton from '../utils/PostSkeleton';

import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 
 class marketplace extends Component {
    state = {
        query:'',
        errors:{},
        type:'Vendo',
        title:'',
        product:'Singole',
        body:'',
        regione:'Abruzzo',
        provincia:'',
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        const {
            user:{
                authenticated, credentials:{
                    handle,
                    ygo,
                    mtg,
                    kf
                }
            }} = this.props;
        
    render() {
       
        return (
           <Grid container>
               <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                <Profile/>
               </Grid>
               <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
               <TextField
                    name="search"
                    floatingLabelText="Cerca"
                    value={this.state.query}
                    onChange={this.searchChange}
                    />
                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleSearch}>
                        Cerca
                    </Button>
                    <Grid item  xs={6} sm={3} >
                    <FormLabel component="legend">Tipo</FormLabel>
                                <RadioGroup aria-label="Tipo" name="type" color="primary" value={this.state.type} onChange={this.radioTypeChange}>
                                    <FormControlLabel value="Vendo" control={<Radio />} label="Vendo" />
                                    <FormControlLabel value="Scambio" control={<Radio />} label="Scambio" />
                                    <FormControlLabel value="Cerco" control={<Radio />} label="Cerco" />
                                </RadioGroup>

                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                    <FormLabel component="legend">Prodotto</FormLabel>
                                <RadioGroup aria-label="Prodotto" name="product" color="primary" value={this.state.product} onChange={this.radioProductChange}>
                                    <FormControlLabel value="Singole" control={<Radio />} label="Singole" />
                                    <FormControlLabel value="Lista" control={<Radio />} label="Lista" />
                                    <FormControlLabel value="Sigillato" control={<Radio />} label="Sigillato" />
                                    <FormControlLabel value="Accessori" control={<Radio />} label="Accessori" />
                                </RadioGroup>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                    <InputLabel id="regioni">Regione</InputLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            labelId="Regione"
                                            id="regioni"
                                            value={this.state.regione}
                                            onChange={this.regionChange}
                                            input={<Input />}
                                            MenuProps={MenuProps}
                                        >
                                        {regioni.map((regione) => (
                                            <MenuItem value={regione.regioneName}>
                                            {regione.regioneName}
                                            </MenuItem>
                                        ))}
                                        </Select>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Provincia</InputLabel>
                                            <Select
                                                labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                                                id="demo-simple-select"
                                                value={this.state.provincia}
                                                onChange={this.whereChange}
                                                disabled={!this.state.regione}
                                            >
                                                {this.state.regione
                                                    ? regioni
                                                        .find(({ regioneName }) => regioneName === this.state.regione)
                                                        .province.map((prov) => (
                                                            <MenuItem value={prov.name}>
                                                                {prov.name}
                                                            </MenuItem>
                                                        ))
                                                    : []}
                                            </Select>
                    </Grid>

                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleFilter}>
                        filter
                    </Button>
                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleReset}>
                        Reset
                       
                    </Button>
                <NewAdv game={game}/>
                {recentAdvsMarkup}
               </Grid>
               <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                
               </Grid>
           </Grid>
        )
    }
}

marketplace.propTypes={
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
    data: state.data,
    user: state.user,
    game: state.UI
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,)(marketplace)
```

But they were showed in a columb. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap elements in a **Box** Material UI component.

```
<Box display="flex" flexDirection="row">
  <Box>
    // Element
  </Box>
  <Box>
    // Element
  </Box>
</Box>
```